# Flexi Auth or Tank Auth for codeigniter auth library

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, tankauth

Which one is better [Tank Auth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) or [Flexi Auth](http://haseydesign.com/flexi-auth/). Which one should I pick. has anyone used anyone of these and can provide some feedback

Comment: you must also look my libary Aauth  

https://github.com/emreakay/CodeIgniter-Aauth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have only used Tank Auth of those two; Tank Auth is good, but gets a little heavy with FB login & other OAuth stuff, from my memory.

Another project to consider is https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth which I use a lot and occasionally contribute to - unlike Tank Auth, which has little maintenance these days, Ion Auth has a very activity community around it and pull requests are very frequent

Comment: I will check it out. I was looking for the one that has an active community.